How to implement logging in multiple classes with same logger
I have been working on a python web crawler for a while now and I'm now wanting to add logging into it so that I can leave it running for a long time and come back to see how it's doing and analyze its behaviors.
My question is, what is the best practice for implementing this? Currently I have my 1 main logger instance which is getting passed around to each of the classes (and sub-classes) of the project to avoid having to create a whole new logger for each instance of each class that is created while running, but I'm starting to think that passing this one instance around all over the place may not be the best way and would like to hear others input. Below is a simple example/illustration of what I'm talking about:
class AppManager:

   def __init__(self):
      self.my_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
      #... logger setup
      self.my_scraper = WebCrawler(self.my_logger) <- pass in member variable into constructor of this class so that I can use the same logger instance

   def some_function(self):
      #...doing something, something goes wrong
      self.my_logger.warning("Warning message") <- log warnings in this class if a method runs into issues

   def get_wp_contenets(self, url):
      contents = self.my_scraper.get_wp_contents(url)

#In another file
class WebCrawler:

   def__init__(self, logger):
      self.my_logger = logger <- store the logger instance as a member of this class
      #...other constructor code

   def get_wp_contents(self, url):
      r = requests.get(url, headers=self._my_header)
      if r.status_code != 200:
         self.my_logger.critical("Bad status code") <- use logger to log to same location as other classes
         #...error handling
         
      return(r.content)

This same behavior is what I have in a small section of my code and works as intended, but, in some cases the WebCrawler would need to create other classes and those sub-classes are being passed the same logger object as the one in the AppManager class. It makes the code ugly and now ever single little class I have in my project all now has a my_logger member and it is all the same as the one defined in the AppManager class. It seems like there should be a better way.

Passing a logger instance to different classes is a common practice, but I would personally like to create my own logging wrapper or utility module that provides a centralized way to access and configure the logger, also you can add project-specific utilities.
A simple utility module implementation would be like:
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Configure the logger with desired settings (level, handlers, formatters, etc.)

def get_logger():
    return logger

Then you can simply import get_logger as per your usecase.
A wrapper would be implemented like below:
import logging

class LoggerWrapper:
    def __init__(self, name, level=logging.INFO):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self.logger.setLevel(level)

        # Add a console handler
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setLevel(level)
        console_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    def debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def warning(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def error(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def critical(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.critical(msg, *args, **kwargs)


Thanks for the comment. To implement your solution, would you be creating new instances of the LoggerWrapper class for each class my AppManager class is going to use? When I parse, validate and save the data I'm getting from the internet I'm creating lots of instances of classes for the tags on the webpages. They are not being used very long, but still need logging. In that case, I'm wondering if creating new instances of the LoggerWrapper would be more 'wasteful' than just passing around the one.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question....  But why aren't you just configuring a root logger and then just getting a new logger per class and letting it flow up to the root logger like so:
import logging
from logging import getLogger

from log_test.crawler import Crawler

logger = getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    filename='my_log.log',
                    filemode='w')

class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info('spinning up the manager')
        for _ in range(5):
            crawler = Crawler()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

crawler module:
from logging import getLogger


logger = getLogger(__name__)

class Crawler:
    idx = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.idx = Crawler.idx
        Crawler.idx += 1
        logger.info("Instantiated crawler %d", self.idx)

resultant log file:
2024-05-25 14:45:20,721 - __main__ - INFO - spinning up the manager
2024-05-25 14:45:20,721 - log_test.crawler - INFO - Instantiated crawler 0
2024-05-25 14:45:20,721 - log_test.crawler - INFO - Instantiated crawler 1
2024-05-25 14:45:20,721 - log_test.crawler - INFO - Instantiated crawler 2
2024-05-25 14:45:20,721 - log_test.crawler - INFO - Instantiated crawler 3
2024-05-25 14:45:20,721 - log_test.crawler - INFO - Instantiated crawler 4

Many variants of this are possible, but this is a the general idea for setting up logging for modules/submodules.  The calls in crawler all refer to the same logger with name log_test.crawler, which passes everything up to the Root Logger, which is configured with the basicConfig() call.

Based on your answer, I think you do understand my question and I think your implementation looks much cleaner. In another part of my code, I parse the webpage contents into objects for different types of tags. The objects being created parse, validate and save data to SQL db. In this case where there are many objects being created and only used for short period of time (but they also need logging) it seems a bit wasteful to create a whole new logger for each of these new instances, which is why I am just passing around the manager's logger. Does the above case change your response at all?

That's a fundamental misunderstanding:  You are not creating new logger objects.  It is created once per class (or more accurately per name of logger) not per object.  You should peruse some of the (quite good) logging dox on the python website.  https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html
